# How to get cookies with socket.io

Tags: node.js, cookies, socket.io

Firstly i created unique cookie value for guests ;

```
// set a cookie
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  // check if client sent cookie
  var cookie = req.cookies.cokkieName;
  if (cookie === undefined)
  {
    // no: set a new cookie
    var randomNumber=Math.random().toString();
    randomNumber=randomNumber.substring(2,randomNumber.length);
    res.cookie('cokkieName',randomNumber, { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: true });
    console.log('cookie have created successfully');
  }
  else
  {
    // yes, cookie was already present
    console.log('cookie exists', cookie);
  }
  next(); // <-- important!
});
```

i can get this cookie value by this line;

```
req.cookies.cokkieName //it is 8164925763849169
```

i want to reach this cookie value with socket.io but if i try to get it with this code;

```
  for(var i in io.sockets.connected) {
    var socket = io.sockets.connected[i].request.headers.cookie;
    console.log(socket);//result is : io=pYb2vzAd8wWWKb......
  }
```

it is logging "io=pYb2vzAd8wWW......." but my cookie value is different , how to get true cookie value .

Note: `io.sockets.connected[i].handshake.headers['cookie']` gives same result

Comment: Can you show code where you set cokkieName?

Comment: Which event comes first in your code, setting the cookie for a particular user in `app.use()` or creating the `socket.io` connection?  If logic serves me, the `io.sockets.connected[i].handshake.headers['cookie']` cookies will be a snapshot of what the cookies were when the socket.io connection was first established (with the original HTTP connection used to create a webSocket connection) and will not be kept up to date if cookie values are added, removed or changed.

Comment: I'm not sure, let me check.... @Osman, what is your end goal with this?

Comment: I get back: 

io=OfE3amPPfpo_LJzqAAAA; cokkieName=07266767090186477

Comment: Here is my code: https://github.com/chapinkapa/socket.io-cookies

Comment: jfriend00, you are right. Even though, you could set this after login and as long as this cookie does not change, you would be fine.

Comment: @chapinkapa - My point is that if the client connects BEFORE the cookie value is set, then `io.sockets.connected[i].handshake.headers['cookie']` will not show the cookie.

Comment: i am trying to fix my problem according to github.com/chapinkapa/socket.io-cookies this app , thank you bro , İt is also works on my localhost , i think Problem is about order of codes

Comment: @OsmanErdi - if the issue is about the ordering of requests/socket connection, then you can probably add code to ensure that the cookie is created/set in the socket.io handshake process so no matter which thing happens first, the cookie will always be in place for the socket connection.

Comment: I see what you mean, my apps have a login page accessed by a RESTful endpoint. This endpoint sets my cookie, and then they are redirected to the app that uses socket.io. It has worked for me. I think a better solution for solving this, though, is using socket.io's rooms.